# Git commands via Intellij Idea UI show following error: .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg: line 32: node: command not found

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Faced for the first time, trying to pull from remote branch via IntelliJ Idea interface. Interesting, that this error occurs allmost on every command, even on checkout, for example. Even more interesting, is that via bash the command work OK.
Does anybody faced this issue?

The following error logged:

**-during checkout attempt**

"Couldn't checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
.git/hooks/post-checkout: line 32: node: command not found"

**-during pull from remote branch attempt**

"Merge Error
.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg: line 32: node: command not found
Not committing merge; use 'git commit' to complete the merge."

Comment: You (perhaps via IntelliJ) told Git to install certain "hooks", but didn't actually install the hooks correctly. This means Git itself works fine but none of your commands do what *you* want them to, because the hook software isn't working, because it's not installed correctly. You'll need to figure out what to do to get the hooks installed correctly. **This is not a Git problem** but rather some other software that you're trying to use *with* Git.

Comment: Also there is a chance that your hooks are not able to access an environment, when you run git operations from IDE. So you may have different environment between your command line and IDE